# Top most view controller class

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have been trying to find the top most view controller class in my application, what I am doing right now is

I have assigned a `UINavigationController` as root view controller in my app. Then on first view I have presented another `UINavigationController` so that I can perform operations like Sign Up and Forgot Password.

I want to check class of the view controller currently displaying on screen.

How can i achieve that, I have checked various methods on google and this site as well.
Please provide me some head start for that.

Comment: When presenting or pushing keep that particular instance in some central place (say in appdelegate) and use it.

Comment: iDev is right. The only way is to store pointer to your active controller. But I don't suggest to share AppDelegate

Comment: Thanks guys, let me check with Samir's solution, but yes keeping a reference in appdelegate is great idea, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you have a `UINavigationController` as a `rootViewController` of the `window`, you have the property `visibleViewController` witch is the view controller associated with the currently visible view in the navigation interface.

[UINavigationController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW1)

Edit :

I you have presented an other `UINavigationController`, the you can use the property `presentedViewController` of `UIViewController` witch returns the view controller that is presented by this view controller, or one of its ancestors in the view controller hierarchy

[UIViewController](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW100)

Something like this (code not compiled) :

In the `appDelegate` for example :

```
UINavigationController *secondNav;
secondNav = (UINavigationController *)[firstNav presentedViewController];
UIViewController *visibleController = [secondNav visibleViewController];
```

Comment: hello @samir, the thing is I am presenting a new UINavigationController on the first view controller of rootviewcontroller which itself is UINavigationController

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
id _vc = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate window] rootViewController];
if ([_vc isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]])
{
    UINavigationController* _nc = (UINavigationController*)_vc;
    if ([[_nc.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:[ViewController class]])
    {
        // view controller is right
    }
}
```